# .htaccess rule: remove parameter

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to create a rule for all GET requests to my site so that:

GET /articles/topic1.html?showall=1

is rewritten as:

GET /articles/topic1.html

I have the following .htaccess file on my Joomla site:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|%3D) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*(.*) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|[|%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|[|%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]

########## This is the Rule I have added ################
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$showall=1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
```

I have added comments on the line that I have added. Unfortunately it doesn't work, the browser warns me I have generated a circular loop....

Any idea how to fix it ??
Thanks
Frank

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing that with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^showall=([0-9])+$
RewriteRule ^articles/topic[0-9]*\.html /articles/topic%1.html? [L]
```

Or if it's really `topic1.html`, then you want this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^showall=1$
RewriteRule ^articles/topic1\.html /articles/topic1.html? [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply: just one thing to note the path  /articles/topic1.html is purely an example. In reality the path can vary, depending on the topic. The only constant is the ?showall=1 query parameter, that I want to remove.